# Eclipse DItto Errors in policy definition

Tags: error-code, eclipse-ditto

I've got some problems in defining a policy in Eclipse Ditto's sandbox; here are some screenshots of the errors I get. I've followed the [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-policy.html) for naming the policy-Id and I've not defined the If-Match and IfNone-Match clauses since they're not compulsory (I don't believe this is the source of my problem). Can someone help me?

[the error I get + the policy definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLsHl.png)

[server + policyid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXpPc.png)

[the other error i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YjXW.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse Ditto sandbox was offline - it is not maintained as "always available" instance, see also the [warning disclaimer](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/sandbox.html) on the project site.

Comment: I've seen your comment on reddit, and this one only now, thank you!